# What is the use of structure having only one element?

Tags: c, variables, struct

Example:

```
struct dummy 
{
    int var;
};
```

Why structures like this are used? Mostly I have seen them in some header files.

The `atomic_t` type is also defined like this. Can't it be defined simply using:

```
typedef int atomic_t;
```

Comment: it is good for extensibility, you might need to add members later

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's more extensible.

Assume that in the future, you realize that `struct dummy` should contain a name field, then you can change the definition of it to:

```
struct dummy 
{
    int var;
    char name[30];
};
```

without changing much of your application code.

Answer (score 8):

Besides extensibility, this idiom also makes it syntactically impossible to do normal arithmetic on types whose meaning is such that that doesn’t make sense semantically.

E.g.:

```
typedef uint32_t myObject;
myObject x, y;
...
y = x + 3; // meaningless, but doesn’t produce an error.
           // may later cause runtime failure.
```

v.s.

```
typedef struct { uint32_t var; } myObject;
myObject x, y;
...
y = x + 3; // syntax error.
```

This may seem contrived, but it is occasionally very useful.

Comment: Seems we both made the same observation. Do you like my example which goes along with the `atomic_t` name from the original question?  I've used the concept myself in designing a flash "file system" for an 8-bit micro where it needed to be possible to form either a virtual page ID or physical page ID from a pair of bytes (implying both were 16 bits, and using anything bigger would have required substantial rework) but I wanted to ensure that I didn't accidentally pass a physical page ID to a routine expecting a logical one or vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

One other use is to pass entire arrays to functions.

```
struct s {
        int a[3];
};

void f1(int a[]) // this evaluates to a pointer, same as void f1(int *a)
{
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));
}

void f2(struct s *obj)
{
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(obj->a));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
        struct s obj;

        obj.a[0] = 1;
        obj.a[1] = 2;
        obj.a[2] = 3;

        f1(a);
        f2(&obj);
        return 0;
}   

// output
// 8
// 12
```

Comment: but this is just the case as you cant parse a as `a[3]` into f1 so its a loose of informations, if you would parse a pointer to a in you also wouldnt need the struct and would get this result after derefferencing.

Answer (score 5):

Not all things that are representable in 32 bits should be treated as numbers.  Even things that have a numeric value may have semantics which would suggest that they need special treatment.  Suppose, for example, that a processor has an "atomic increment" instruction but it's slower than a "normal" increment instruction.  If one wants to atomically increment `fnord` in one place and decrement it in another, one could use:

```
volatile int fnord;
...
atomic_inc(&fnord);
...
atomic_dec(&fnord);
```

A problem with that, however, is that if one of the places that is supposed to increment `fnord` happens to use `fnord++` rather than `atomic_inc(&fnord);`, the compiler will perfectly happily generate a "normal" increment instruction, and the code may work most of the time, but it could fail in hard-to-track down fashion.

Replacing the `int` with a structure (and defining `atomic_inc` inline functions to work with it) would prevent erroneous code like `fnord++;` from compiling.  It wouldn't guard against `fnord.var++;` but would give a programmer a chance to examine the structure and see what the right way to increment it would be.

Comment: This is very useful in large-scale projects. Rust also recommends this pattern; they call it [newtype](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/features/types/newtype.html).

Answer (score 4):

Mostly it is to keep compatibility, as maybe earlier the structure had additional elements.

Or as it could be intended to add other elements later.
(or even an itnernal version of the structure has more than just one member (what I realy could imagine for `atomic_t`-type.)